# How to use powershell to get the next word, in this case it's number, from a specific word in the output

Tags: powershell, text-processing, command-substitution

How to use powershell to echo the next word, in this case it's number, from a specific word in the output

For example this command

```
powershell echo "$(chia wallet show -w standard_wallet | Select-String -Pattern "Spendable:")
```

Gives this line that has the specific word "Spendable:" from the output

```
   -Spendable:             0.255502536372 xch (255502536372 mojo)
```

How do I get only the next word in this line which is 0.255502536372 in this case

Comment: Your code does not work for me. first its missing a ' " ' at the end. please fix the code that you pasted.

Comment: It works on my command prompt, not sure how to fix it.  Here is the result 
```C:\Users\kuy>powershell echo "$(chia wallet show -w standard_wallet | Select-String -Pattern "Spendable:")``` 
I typed it like that and it gives this result
`-Spendable:             0.266388243374 xch (266388243374 mojo)`

Comment: In powershell this one gives the same output ```PS C:\Users\kuy> powershell echo '"$(chia wallet show -w standard_wallet | Select-String -Pattern "Spendable")'``` of 
`-Spendable:             0.266388243374 xch (266388243374 mojo)
PS C:\Users\kuy>`

Comment: In your post you did not add single quote in your comment you added single quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a Positive Lookbehind to match for the requested.

```
powershell "(chia wallet show -w standard_wallet | Select-String -Pattern '(?<=Spendable:\s+).\.\d+').Matches.Value"
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/DsJhyg/1)